# Opencart website on WAMP redirecting to live website

Tags: localhost, wamp, opencart, wampserver

I've copied the files and DB from a live opencart website to run on local WAMP installation.

on going /localhost/ is redirecting to live website on the internet.

I don't see anything wrong with the htaccess file:

```
# STARTNITRO
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
ExpiresActive On

#CSS JS XML TXT - 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
</FilesMatch>

#JPG JPEG PNG GIF SWF SVG - 1 MONTH
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF|SWF|SVG)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
Header set Last-Modified "Wed, 05 Jun 2009 06:40:46 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

#OTF WOFF TTF ICO PDF FLV - 1 MONTH
<FilesMatch "\.(otf|ico|pdf|flv|woff|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
# ENDNITRO
# STARTCOMPRESSNITRO
# ENDCOMPRESSNITRO


# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 



# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.



# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com


Options +FollowSymlinks


# Prevent Directoy listing 

Options -Indexes



# Prevent Direct Access to files

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">

 Order deny,allow

 Deny from all

</FilesMatch>



# SEO URL Settings

RewriteEngine On

# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 



RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]



### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 

### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.

### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.



# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:

# php_flag register_globals off



# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:

# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off



# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try

# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M



# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

# php_value post_max_size 999M



# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

# php_value max_execution_time 200

        # 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

# php_value max_input_time 200


# 7. disable open_basedir limitations

# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

I have checked the DB for entries which may point to the live website and corrected them. Changed the values in config.php files as well.

Windows host file has the localhost entry.

Any ideas what I may have missed?

OpenCart 1.5.6.4

Thanks.

Comment: Well quite obviously you have missed something, so check it all again. Chech what you did against [this](http://isenselabs.com/posts/step-by-step-opencart-migration-to-a-new-server) or a similiar tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.php files both admin and the public one see if you have defined the path as localhost instead of the live URL

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://localhost/');
```